# Converter uma String JSON para um Array do Objeto JAVA

Tags: java, json, array, firebase

Olá, não estou conseguindo fazer a conversão, minha string está vindo assim.

```
{
  "empresa1":
  {
    "category_id" : "Item 1",
    "id" : 1,
    "imagePath" : "imagem",
    "name" : "empresa 1",
    "short_desc" : "desc da empresa 1"
  },
  "empresa2":
  {
    "category_id" : "Item 1",
    "id" : 2,
    "imagePath" : "imagem",
    "name" : "empresa2",
    "short_desc" : "desc da empresa 2"
  },
  "empresa3":
  {
    "category_id" : "Item 1",
    "id" : 3,
    "imagePath" : "imagem",
    "name" : "empresa3",
    "short_desc" : "desc da empresa 3"
  }
}
```

Preciso converter esse texto pra um array do meu objeto e pra depois popular minha tabela.

Obrigado.[image: Registros]

Comment: Quer converter para uma classe empresa ou apenas um map contendo chave e valor?

Comment: Preciso converter esses dados pra um array da minha classe empresa, o que está me dificultando é que a string vem com a "raiz" de cada cadastro (empresa1, empresa2, empresa3), lembrando que essa raiz sou eu que digito o nome.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente você vai precisar criar uma classe chamada `Empresa`, segue:

```
public class Empresa {

    private Integer id;
    private String idCategoria;
    private String imagePath;
    private String name;
    private String shortDesc;

    public Integer getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(Integer id) {this.id = id;}

    public String getIdCategoria() {return idCategoria;}
    public void setIdCategoria(String idCategoria) {this.idCategoria = idCategoria;}

    public String getImagePath() {return imagePath;}
    public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {this.imagePath = imagePath;}

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public String getShortDesc() {return shortDesc;}
    public void setShortDesc(String shortDesc) {this.shortDesc = shortDesc;}
}
```

Agora crie um `List` do tipo `Empresa` e um `JSONObject` passando o `json` que está em `String` como parâmetro.

```
String jsonString = "{ \"empresa1\": { \"category_id\": \"Item 1\", \"id\": 1, \"imagePath\": \"imagem\", \"name\": \"empresa 1\", \"short_desc\": \"desc da empresa 1\" }, \"empresa2\": { \"category_id\": \"Item 1\", \"id\": 2, \"imagePath\": \"imagem\", \"name\": \"empresa2\", \"short_desc\": \"desc da empresa 2\" }, \"empresa3\": { \"category_id\": \"Item 1\", \"id\": 3, \"imagePath\": \"imagem\", \"name\": \"empresa3\", \"short_desc\": \"desc da empresa 3\" } }";

JSONObject jsonObjectEmpresas = new JSONObject(jsonString);

List<Empresa> listaDeEmpresas = new ArrayList<Empresa>();
```

Após fazer isso, existem algumas formas de você percorrer as chaves e pegar seus respectivos valores. Vou postar dois exemplos.

Usando a interface `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<String> iteratorEmpresas = jsonObjectEmpresas.keys();
while (iteratorEmpresas.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject dadosEmpresa = jsonObjectEmpresas.getJSONObject(iteratorEmpresas.next());

   Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
        empresa.setId(dadosEmpresa.getInt("id"));
        empresa.setName(dadosEmpresa.getString("name"));
        empresa.setIdCategoria(dadosEmpresa.getString("category_id"));
        empresa.setImagePath(dadosEmpresa.getString("imagePath"));
        empresa.setShortDesc(dadosEmpresa.getString("short_desc"));

        listaDeEmpresas.add(empresa);
}
```

Usando a interface `Set`:

```
for (String keyEmpresa : jsonObjectEmpresas.keySet()) {
    JSONObject dadosEmpresa = jsonObjectEmpresas.getJSONObject(keyEmpresa);

        Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
        empresa.setId(dadosEmpresa.getInt("id"));
        empresa.setName(dadosEmpresa.getString("name"));
        empresa.setIdCategoria(dadosEmpresa.getString("category_id"));
        empresa.setImagePath(dadosEmpresa.getString("imagePath"));
        empresa.setShortDesc(dadosEmpresa.getString("short_desc"));

        listaDeEmpresas.add(empresa);
}
```

Percorrendo a lista de empresas:

```
for (Empresa empresa : listaDeEmpresas) {
    System.out.println("-----");
    System.out.println("ID:" + empresa.getId());
    System.out.println("NAME:" + empresa.getName());
    System.out.println("ID CATEGORIA:" + empresa.getIdCategoria());
    System.out.println("IMG PATH:" + empresa.getImagePath());
    System.out.println("SHORT DESC:" + empresa.getShortDesc());
}
```

Para trabalhar com json e parse automático de forma simples, recomendo o uso da biblioteca [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) ou [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Comment: Quando eu tento executar o JSONObject jsonObjectEmpresas = new JSONObject(jsonComercio); ele da erro falando que são tipos incompatíveis, dizendo que String não pode ser convertida pra boolean.

Comment: O seu jsonComercio é uma string?

Comment: Sim, é uma string -  response = firebase.get("commerce");
        String jsonComercio = response.getRawBody();

Comment: Estranho. O que vem no System.out.println(jsonComercio)?

Comment: Exatamente a resposta que mandei lá na primeira pergunta {
  "empresa1":
  {
    "category_id" : "Item 1",
    "id" : 1,
    "imagePath" : "imagem",
    "name" : "empresa 1",
    "short_desc" : "desc da empresa 1"
  },
  "empresa2":
  {
    "category_id" : "Item 1",
    "id" : 2,
    "imagePath" : "imagem",
    "name" : "empresa2",
    "short_desc" : "desc da empresa 2"
  },
  "empresa3":
  {
    "category_id" : "Item 1",
    "id" : 3,
    "imagePath" : "imagem",
    "name" : "empresa3",
    "short_desc" : "desc da empresa 3"
  }
}

Comment: O pacote que vc importou é o org.json.JSONObject?

Comment: import net.sf.json.JSONObject; foi uma biblioteca que achei com o nome json-lib-2.4-jdk15

Comment: O jar correto você pode baixar no repositório do maven: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20160810/json-20160810.jar

Comment: Deu certo! Porém eu preciso pegar além dos atributos, essa raiz (empresa1, empresa2, empresa3), pois vou usá-la para fazer o update do registro, você sabe como? Pensei até em criar uma segunda classe, com os mesmos atributos da classe empresas, porém com um a mais para salvar esse campo, mas não sei como.

Comment: Sim, no primeiro exemplo a raiz é o iteratorEmpresas.next() e no segundo é a variavel keyEmpresa.

Comment: Utilizei o segundo exemplo (keyEmpresa), não entendi a lógica de como funciona mas consegui fazer, peguei a raiz e salvei em uma segunda classe pra trabalhar com ele, exatamente o que eu precisava, muito obrigado Diego!!! :D

Comment: Bom que deu certo. Se poder marcar a resposta como útil eu agradeço. Abs

Comment: Já marquei como útil, porém disse que votos de usuários com menos de 15 de reputação são registrados mas não mudam a pontuação mostrada no post. Valeu.